# kodein, inject data to simple class

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, kodein

i'm new on kotlin and kodein development.
I want to inject data to a simple class which extends nothing.

I have my `MainActivity` which extends `KodeinAppCompatActivity()`,
my fragment which extends `KodeinSupportFragment()` calls a function from my simple class `CallType`. But this function must to change a boolean from an other simple class `ConnectivitySate`. I don't want to use static value.

Below, my code :

```
    class App : Application(), KodeinAware {

override val kodein by Kodein.lazy {
    import(autoAndroidModule(this@App))

    bind<CallType>() with instance(CallType())
    bind<ConnectivityState>() with instance(ConnectivityState())
    bind<ContactData>() with instance(ContactData())

}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(androidActivityScope.lifecycleManager)
}
```

MainActivity :

```
    class MainActivity : KodeinAppCompatActivity() {
```

My Fragment :

```
class JournalFragment : KodeinSupportFragment(){

  private val callType: CallType by instance()

  @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    initializeInjector()
}

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: 
          ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

      // !! CALL MY FUNCTION !!
      callType.call(callType.callNumber)

  }

 ....

 @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
 override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    destroyInjector()
}
```

My simple class :

```
class CallType {

fun call(number: String) {

   // !! I want to change gsmState value from ConnectivityState class
   connectivityState.gsmState = true

}
```

My ConnectivityState class :

```
class ConnectivityState {

    var gsmState = false

}
```

It is an example among many others, because in lots of situations, i'm blocked like that. I have try lots of things but i always have like error : `value not injected`

Thank you very much for your reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `super.onCreate()`, it calls `onCreateView`, so the line `callType.call(callType.callNumber)` is called **before** `initializeInjector()`.

Note that you should always call `initializeInjector()` **before** calling `super.onCreate()`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    initializeInjector()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

Comment: Thak you but it's weird because it works when i call  `callType.call (callType.callNumber)`, but i'll change it. My problem is in CallType class. I want to inject value in this class. But i don't know how because it extends nothing.

Comment: i'm really blocked... if you have any idea. Thak you for your help

Comment: You can pass it the `kodein` property at constructor, and then use standard retrieval methods : https://salomonbrys.github.io/Kodein/#_dependency_retrieval

Comment: Thank you, but I find it hard to understand in your doc. Can you show me an example with my `CallType` and `ConnectivitySate` above classes, for example ?